# Apktool 2.4.1 NullPointerException

Tags: apk, decompiler, apktool

Today when I used apktool to decompile some apks, I got the error below:

```
I: Using Apktool 2.4.1 on 025A.apk
I: Loading resource table...
I: Decoding AndroidManifest.xml with resources...
I: Loading resource table from file: C:\Users\potter\AppData\Local\apktool\framework\1.apk
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
        at org.xmlpull.renamed.MXSerializer.attribute(MXSerializer.java:631)
        at org.xmlpull.v1.wrapper.classic.XmlSerializerDelegate.attribute(XmlSerializerDelegate.java:106)
        at org.xmlpull.v1.wrapper.classic.StaticXmlSerializerWrapper.writeStartTag(StaticXmlSerializerWrapper.java:267)
        at org.xmlpull.v1.wrapper.classic.StaticXmlSerializerWrapper.event(StaticXmlSerializerWrapper.java:211)
        at brut.androlib.res.decoder.XmlPullStreamDecoder$1.event(XmlPullStreamDecoder.java:84)
        at brut.androlib.res.decoder.XmlPullStreamDecoder.decode(XmlPullStreamDecoder.java:142)
        at brut.androlib.res.decoder.XmlPullStreamDecoder.decodeManifest(XmlPullStreamDecoder.java:154)
        at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ResFileDecoder.decodeManifest(ResFileDecoder.java:162)
        at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.decodeManifestWithResources(AndrolibResources.java:204)
        at brut.androlib.Androlib.decodeManifestWithResources(Androlib.java:134)
        at brut.androlib.ApkDecoder.decode(ApkDecoder.java:122)
        at brut.apktool.Main.cmdDecode(Main.java:170)
        at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:76)
```

But at the same time, I can use `aapt2 dump badging 025A.apk` to get the package name.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/issues/2300#issuecomment-612674987), downgrading to 2.4.0 can mitigate this issue, through the experiment.